# Calculate total price by listening to change events on other input fields react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have this component in React JS. I have 3 input fields. One for pounds, one for PPP (Price Per Pound) and the other one is the total. A user inputs the pounds they want in the input field, I already pass the PPP as a value by default, and then I want to calculate the total by multiplying price * ppp as the user is typing.

This is the whole component:

```html
class NewTransaction extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pounds: '',
            ppp: 2.10,
            total: 0
        };

        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handlePoundsChange = this.handlePoundsChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePPPChange = this.handlePPPChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTotalChange = this.handleTotalChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){}

    handlePoundsChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handlePPPChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleTotalChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let pounds = $("#pounds").val();
        let ppp = $("#ppp").val();
        let total = ppp * pounds;
        console.log(total);

        axios.post('/api/add/transaction', {
            pounds: pounds,
            ppp: ppp,
            total: total
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#pounds").val('');
                $("#ppp").val('');
                $("#total").val('');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
            });
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container">
                    <form className="container" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                        <table className="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Pounds</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="pounds" id="pounds" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pounds..." onChange={this.handlePoundsChange} required />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Price</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="ppp" id="ppp" className="form-control" value="2.10" onChange={this.handlePPPChange} required />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="total" id="total" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleTotalChange} />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <input
                                type="submit"
                                className="btn btn-block btn-primary"
                                value="Customer Checkout"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So if a user enters 2 in the pounds input field, React will go in and multiply 2 * the PPP (in this case 2.10), and I want that to show up in the "**Total**" input field right away.

Comment: why are you calling setState and changing `value` instead of the real property? for example `handleTotalChange(event) {
        this.setState({total: event.target.value});
    }`

Comment: Alright I changed that, good catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your fixed code. Should work like a charm.

```
class NewTransaction extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pounds: 0,
      ppp: 2.10,
      total: 0
    };

    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handlePoundsChange = this.handlePoundsChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePPPChange = this.handlePPPChange.bind(this);
    //this.handleTotalChange = this.handleTotalChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){}

  handlePoundsChange(event) {
    this.setState(...this.state, {pounds: event.target.value});
  }

  handlePPPChange(event) {
    this.setState(...this.state, {ppp: event.target.value});
  }

  handleTotalChange(event) {
    //this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let pounds = this.state.pounds;
    let ppp = this.state.ppp;
    let total = ppp * pounds;
    console.log(total);
    const self = this;
    axios.post('/api/add/transaction', {
      pounds: pounds,
      ppp: ppp,
      total: total
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        self.setState({pounds: '', ppp: '', total: ''});
        // $("#pounds").val('');
        // $("#ppp").val('');
        // $("#total").val('');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
  }


  render() {
    const total = this.state.pounds * this.state.ppp;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form className="container" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <table className="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Pounds</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="pounds" id="pounds" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pounds..." value={this.state.pounds} onChange={this.handlePoundsChange} required />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Price</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="ppp" id="ppp" className="form-control" value={this.state.ppp} onChange={this.handlePPPChange} required />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Total</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="total" id="total" className="form-control" value={total} />
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <input
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-block btn-primary"
              value="Customer Checkout"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great. Will take a look at this, and compare it with my code. Thank you.

Comment: just replace `self.setState({pounds: '', ppp: '', total: ''});` with `self.setState({pounds: 0, ppp: 2.10, total: 0});` (in the axios response function)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of strange things in your code.
1. Why are you calling `setState` and changing the `value` property instead of the relevant one?
for example shouldnt this:

```
handlePoundsChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
```

become this:

```
handlePoundsChange(event) {
        this.setState({pounds: event.target.value});
    }
```

2. You are not binding the values from the state in the inputs.
this:

```
<input type="text" name="pounds" id="pounds" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pounds..." onChange={this.handlePoundsChange} required />
```

should be like this more or less:

```
<input value={this.state.pounds} type="text" name="pounds" id="pounds" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pounds..." onChange={this.handlePoundsChange} required  />
```

3. Why is your `total` element is an `<input />`? you want the client to be abale to change that no matter what the other inputs value is?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention, you don't need `jQuery` here to reset the inputs. when you done with your ajax call you can just reset the state properties and the binding of the inputs will do that job for you.

Comment: You definitely have some good points there. I do need to go back and refactor this code. Binding it to the value is the way to do it. I will stay with jQuery though because Im already using it in other parts in my components.

Comment: note that changing the `DOM` like that can make debugging a living hell :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the total input box value to the state.

```
<input value={this.state.total} type="text" name="total" id="total" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleTotalChange} />
```

Then if you want the value of the total to change when the user inputs Pounds and PPP you need to update your total state in the handlePoundsChange and handlePPPChange functions.

```
handlePoundsChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      total: event.target.value * this.state.ppp
  });
}

handlePPPChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      total: event.target.value * this.state.pounds
  });
}
```